# delete element from left side of tandem_select_jquery_plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following tandem_select_jquery_plugin library in my project and this is example of it :
http://craic.github.io/tandem_select_jquery_plugin/tandem_select_demo_1.html

I want to delete the element from the left side when I move them to the right side instead of making it grey

I tried to change class tandem-select-option-disabled to 
display :none ... but it still showing the elements !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you i have edit the `tandem_select.js` file for you please replace this with your `tandem_select.js` file.
Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ngA6J/3/)**

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush check demo now :)